# Understanding the double dual space in a concrete example

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

I am trying to explore the assertion that in finite vector spaces $V^{**}=V.$ This statement is most likely incorrect, as stated on [this accepted answer in MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37538/152225), although it seems clearly  spelled out as true on [this precise point of a youtube series by Ben Garside](https://youtu.be/6PEKr7vWsrw?t=8m26s), excellent in its didactic approach, or [in this minute on a lecture by Frederic Schuller](https://youtu.be/mbv3T15nWq0?t=59m31s), part of the series [Gravity and Light](https://gravity-and-light.herokuapp.com).

But I'd like to focus on a concrete example of a vector space presented [here](https://youtu.be/mbv3T15nWq0?t=16m) as defined over the set of polynomials of fixed degree $(N=7)$ on the interval $(-1,+1)$:

$$\mathcal P := \{p:(-1,+1)\rightarrow \mathbb R \, \vert \, p(x)=\sum_{n=0}^N p_nx^n\}$$

So the vectors are polynomials.

And as an [example of a map in $V^*$](https://youtu.be/mbv3T15nWq0?t=47m17s) taking in a polynomial $p(x)$ and sending it to a real number the definite integral of the polynomial from $0$ to $1$:

$$I(p):= \int_0^1 dx\,p(x).$$

So the question is, **What would be a good example of $V^{**}$ based on this polynomial example that let's you see how we "somehow return" to $V$?**

Or, in other words, how can you take a definite integral, and send it back to a polynomial? Or, if the statement $V=V^{**}$ is incorrect, can I still have an illustrative example of a map in $V^{**}?$

---

NOTE: At the end of the lecture by Frederic Schuller basis vectors for $V$ are derived for the polynomial example (with $N=3$) as $\large e_a(x)=x^a:$

$$\begin{matrix}e_0(x)=x^0\\
e_1(x)=x^1\\
e_2(x)=x^2\\
e_3(x)=x^3\end{matrix}$$

and the basis for $V^*$ as $\large \epsilon^a=\frac{\frac{d^{(a)}}{dx} p(x)\,\vert_{x=0}}{a!}$, which should produce the coefficient for the term $a$ in $p(x)$, only that if the $p(x)$ is the basis for $V$ with all coefficients equal to $1$ when $\epsilon_a$ acts as a function on $e_a$ it will act as a [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function):

$$\epsilon^a(e_b) =\delta^b_a$$

Comment: You should know that we *never* have $V^{**} = V$. Rather, the vector space $V$ is isomorphic to $V^{**}$.

Comment: @user259242 Right, I wouldn't want to be side-tracked by this point, because I'm really after the example, but I wonder if you have taken a peek at the linked (and appropriately timed) videoclips stating $V^{**}=V$. If so I would really appreciate a comment on that.

Comment: The members of $V^{**}$ are functions on the domain $V^*$. The members of $V$ need not be functions at all.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is not true that $V^{**} = V$. Rather, $V$ is isomorphic to $V^{**}$, via the linear map $\psi$ which takes a vector $v$ to the map $v \mapsto \phi_v$, where $\phi_v\colon V^* \to k$ is given by $\phi_v(f) = f(v)$.

You describe a vector space $\mathcal{P}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and an element $I$ of the dual of $\mathcal{P}$. You then want to associate to this element a vector in $\mathcal{P}$. Indeed, a finite dimensional vector space is isomorphic to its dual, but there is in general no natural isomorphism. In fact, we get an isomorphism for every non-degenerate bilinear form on our vector space. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form

Answer (score 1):

A notation that is often used is the *duality pairing*, the bilinear map $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle:W\times V\to K$ allowing one to treat the two linear spaces more equally, before calling one dual to the other. In your example you could write $I(p)=\langle I ,p \rangle$ and take the viewpoint that it's the polynomials that "act" on the linear map $I$.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to present a concrete example, involving a vector space of polynomials, but simpler than the example mentioned in the question.

The vector space considered, is a two dimensional one, and figures in Problem 11.2 of Lipschutz and Lipson, Reference 1.

Problem 11.2, starts with a definition of our $V$, I quote

> Let $V=${$ ~a+bt~:~a,b\in R$}, the vector space of real polynomials of degree $\leq$1.

Reference 1 gives us a basis for the ‘Dual Space’ to $V$, $V^*$, I quote

> Find the basis {$v_1,v_2$} that is dual to the basis {$\phi _1, \phi _2$} of $V^*$ defined by
> \begin{equation*}
> \phi _1 (f(t))=\int_0^1~f(t)~dt~~~\text{and}~~~\phi_2(f(t))=\int_0^2~f(t)~dt
> \end{equation*}

So, {$\phi _1, \phi _2$} is, according to Reference 1, a basis of our $V^*$.

I am going to write ‘Linear Functionals’ (LF’s) with a hat on, and to use the following definitions, rather than the notation of Reference 1

\begin{equation*}
\hat{\phi} _1 (f(t))=\int_0^1~dt~f(t)~~~\text{and}~~~\hat{\phi}_2(f(t))=\int_0^2~dt~f(t)
\end{equation*}

Now, and I will expand afterwards, the example I intend can be presented briefly as,

\begin{align*}
V&=\text{\{} ~(a+bt)~:~a,b\in R\text{\}}   \\
V^*&=\text{\{} ~ \hat{\phi} :     \hat{\phi} = (c_1\hat{\phi} _1  +c_2 \hat{\phi} _2)       ,~c_1,c_2\in R\text{\}}  \\
V^{**}&=\text{\{} ~( \widehat{a+bt} )~:~a,b\in R\text{\}}   
\end{align*}

where the LF’s $\widehat{a+bt}$ are defined by a ‘Natural Map’
\begin{equation*}
(\widehat{a+bt})(\hat{\phi} )=\hat{\phi} (a+bt)
\end{equation*}

**In more detail**
\begin{align*}
V&=\text{\{} ~(a+bt)~:~a,b\in R\text{\}}   \\
V^*&=\text{\{} ~ \hat{\phi} :     \hat{\phi} = (c_1\hat{\phi} _1  +c_2 \hat{\phi} _2)  ,~c_1,c_2\in R\text{\}}  \\
\end{align*}

\begin{equation*}
\hat{\phi} _1  =\int_0^1~dt~~~\text{and}~~~ \hat{\phi} _2 =\int_0^2~dt
\end{equation*}
\begin{align*}
\hat{\phi} _1 (a+bt) & =\int_0^1~dt ~(a+bt)\\
\hat{\phi} _2 (a+bt)&=\int_0^2~dt ~(a+bt)
\end{align*}

\begin{equation*}
V^{**}=\text{\{} ~( \widehat{a+bt} )~:~a,b\in R\text{\}} ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
\end{equation*}
where the LF’s $\widehat{a+bt}$ are defined by a ‘Natural Map’
\begin{equation*}
(\widehat{a+bt})(\hat{\phi} )=\hat{\phi} (a+bt)
\end{equation*}

The right hand side, RHS, of the above is

\begin{align*}
\hat{\phi} (a+bt) &= (c_1\hat{\phi} _1  +c_2 \hat{\phi} _2) (a+bt) \\
&=  c_1~\int_0^1~dt ~(a+bt)  + c_2~\int_0^2~dt ~(a+bt)
\end{align*}

The left hand side, LHS, is, well, equal to the RHS of the equation, but you could write, with the first step below, by the definition of the LF's, $\widehat{a+bt}$.
\begin{align*}
(\widehat{a+bt})(\hat{\phi} )&= \hat{\phi} (a+bt) \\
&= (c_1\hat{\phi} _1  +c_2 \hat{\phi} _2) (a+bt) \\
&=  c_1~\int_0^1~dt ~(a+bt)  + c_2~\int_0^2~dt ~(a+bt)
\end{align*}

So the RHS and LHS of the natural map, are the same expressions and give the same number from $R$.

Reference

1 Seymour Lipschutz, Ph.D., Marc Lipson, Ph.D., Schaum’s Outlines, Linear Algebra, Fourth Edition, The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc. (2009)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!